# Dojo Tab Styles are not working for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dojo

For Dojo TabContainer I am setting two Tabs with titles: **Role**, **Admin**.

My tabs are not not at all styled.

In the browser those two Tabs are coming as **RoleAdmin**

How can I style tabs?

Can anybody please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below great technique in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331920/DataGrid-View-with-CRUD-operations-using-Dojo-Data

And the answer is:

```
<script>
    dojo.query("body").addClass("claro");
</script>
```

With the above answer, my Tabs are looking like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add a theme.

Add the css to the head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="PATH_TO_DOJO/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
```

Add the theme to the body tag

```
<body class="claro">
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/themes.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Craig. Reference to claro.css is already existing in my code. I am using ASP.NET MVC hence, I don't know how to set body class. Can you suggest me!

Comment: You will need to post some code.  What does your razor view look like?